# Gradient Boosting interpretation of residuals

Tags: regression, boosting, adaboost

So I came across this [sentence](https://www.mygreatlearning.com/blog/gradient-boosting/) (from an e-learning website):

> By training on the residuals of the model, this is an alternative means to give more importance to misclassified observations. Intuitively, new weak learners are being added to concentrate on the areas where the existing learners are performing poorly.

However, I still am unable to see where/how in the algorithm this happens. How is it able to concentrate in the areas where previous learners did poorly?

Here a picture of the pseudo-code:

[image]

Comment: Caterina, if you are quoting the above extract from a certain literature, book, website, it would be appreciable if you cite the proper source.

Comment: Just added the information.

Comment: The second quote sounds like adaboost rather than gradient boosting.

Comment: @BenReiniger - you have it right - the linked journal paper explicitly states that AdaBoost inspired the "novel method" they are proposing.

Comment: I removed it from the question, I'm still unsure of how the algorithm "detects" those areas.

Comment: Gradient boosting doesn't detect any areas, it just iterates as in the pseudo-code.  The biggest errors in the previous step are the ones most important to fit in the subsequent step in a way not too dissimilar to the way that the more extreme values of $y$ are, typically, the ones by which a least squares line will be most influenced.

Comment: @jbowman I'm just curious as to where exactly this happens, would you be able to show the math as an answer? Or the specific line in the pseudo code? My interpretation was this:  the base learner $h_m$ is trained to predict the residuals which are then combined with a proportionate weight $\gamma$ to the previous prediction $F_{m-1}$, and thus the larger the residuals the better the current prediction with respect to learner $F_{m-1}$ at that region. Let me know if this is correct. I mention "region" in the context of regression trees for example.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  If your loss function is squared error / 2, then the pseudo-residuals are the usual residuals ($-(1/2)\partial (y-f)^2 / \partial f = (y-f)$) hence the name "pseudo-residuals" to cover both this and the general case.  The relevant line of code is 2.2 - "Fit a base learner..."